# find divisors of a number using while loops

Tags: while-loop, return

I am new to coding and I would like some assistance with how to find the divisors of a number (I would like to add them all together and return the result). Ive seen some examples in different post, but they used for loops. I only know, and can only use, while loops.

anything helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use while loop to find positive divisors of a number in the following way:

```
def find_divisors(n):
    if n==0:
        return []
    if n<0:
        n=-n
    divisors=[]
    i=n
    while(i):
        if n%i==0:
            divisors.append(i)
        i=i-1
    return divisors
```